# Android Studio 2021 (Chipmunk)Clarity on What Gradle version to use?

Tags: java, android, gradle

We created and released a Lollipop project (Android SDK 5.1) in 1/2015.  It has been running perfectly and has not been touched since then.
Recently, there is a need to re-open the project but, as can be expected, many things have changed regarding Android within the last 7+ years.
The project IDE has been upgraded to Android Studio 2021: Chipmunk (AS).  The project was extracted from a ZIP file into ../AndroidStudioProjects.  When opening the project, several errors result, but the two that I need understanding with, as an Android noob-with-some-Java-knowledge, concern Gradle and JRE:

- Which Gradle to use for a Lollipop project? - Does the project determine which Gradle version to use? Or, does AS version determine which Gradle version to use? Or, ???
- Which JRE to use for a Lollipop project? - What determines which JRE to use?

I Googled these topics for several days but am going in circles.

Comment: I think important info is missing like is your project for Google Play Store release or not, see https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk. If it is, then a full review/rebuild of the app may be in order to meet modern requirements and it no longer can stay a Lollipop project. If only for internal use again what changes are required by business need to be identified. Without showing what errors you a getting, readers can only guess.

Comment: @Morrison Chang: Thank you for your reply.  My question probably reflects how clueless I am getting this project set up again. In a nutshell, the project is used exclusively in private venues that have an isolated LAN dedicated to this system.  The APK is sideloaded on to a Samsung TAB 4 10.1 tablet. There may be up to 7 tablets in a system.  Since the Samsung tablets in use cannot be upgraded beyond Lollipop we were hoping to be able keep the project "frozen" but make minor tweaks to it and sideload the modified APK.  I confess I seem to be way out of my league with this.

Comment: A project from 2015 is around the transition from Eclipse to Android Studio. There has been a number of changes to the gradle build system which if motivated is probably resolvable. Without knowing what errors you are getting and anything that old might be an Eclipse project (e.g. an Ant build.xml), I would just create a new modern Android project and copy over the code/resource files to get a working version. Regardless on which path you take, you should be posting what you've done/errors encountered.

Comment: @Morrison Chang: Thank you again for your help!  Sorry to keep the errors a mystery. I was hoping to get a general idea of the required steps to set up a Lollipop project in the modern AS IDE.  I think you have cut to the chase with your advise in your last comment, I am going to give that a try. That is, create a modern project, then copy over the sources and resolve any errors from that point.